# How to integrate Google Chat REST API into a website?

Tags: google-workspace, google-chat, google-chat-api

I'm trying to integrate the Google Chat REST API into a website so as to be able to talk to customers. On Google Cloud API Library the Google Chat API is displayed and can be enabled but still I have no clue how to integrate it into my website.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed all the information inside [Google Chat API](https://developers.google.com/chat), and I was not able to find an option to integrate Google Chat with a Website.

Maybe you can add a request in the [Google Missing features](https://developers.google.com/chat/support#missing_features).