# How to add a hyperlink to a chat with a Google Chat Bot at the botton of the page

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink, chatbot, google-chat, google-sites-2016

I am trying to add a link to open a chat with the Google Chat bot or a link to the Google Chat conversation with a bot at the bottom (corner side) of my website/webpage.

Put differently, I am looking for a way to embed a Google Chat window in my website. If this is not possible, I would settle for a way to add a link that would redirect the user to a Google Chat bot.

How can I do this?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/70778608/1595451

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/73166405/1595451

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid it is not possible to do this at the moment. The users need to add the bot to their respective Google account and the only way to add it is through the UI from Google Chat following the steps noted [here](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/7655820?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#:%7E:text=Find%20apps%20%26%20add%20them%20in%20Google%20Chat%20or%20Gmail), therefore even if you could embed a chat to the website it would need to be the user's personal chat using the Google Chat's home page, and they would still need to manually search for your app since there is no way to create a direct link for installation given that there is no kind of Google Chat marketplace for bots or apps.

You can submit this as a feature request of the Google Chat API to see if Google can make it available in the future by going to [this link](https://developers.google.com/chat/support#developer_product_feedback)